# Combine multiple arrays of same variable in a single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my code.

```
$users = array(83,84);

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $queryselectuser =  mysqli_query($connect,"SOME QUERY");
    while($rec_file=mysqli_fetch_array($queryselectuser)) 
    {
       $l['request_id']= $rec_file['request_id'];
       $l['fixer_id']= $rec_file['fixer_id'];
       print_r($l);
    }
}
```

**And this is the result I am getting.**

```
Array
(
  [request_id] => 1502
  [fixer_id] => 84
)

Array
(
  [request_id] => 1500
  [fixer_id] => 84
)
Array
(
  [request_id] => 1503
  [fixer_id] => 83
)

Array
(
  [request_id] => 1501
  [fixer_id] => 83
)
```

**But my expected o/p is :**

I want separate array for each user.

*Array for user 84:*
Array (
Array
(
[request_id] => 1502
[fixer_id] => 84
),

Array
(
[request_id] => 1500
[fixer_id] => 84
)

)

*Array for user 83.*

Array (
Array
(
[request_id] => 1503
[fixer_id] => 83
),

Array
(
[request_id] => 1501
[fixer_id] => 83
)

)

**What I had Tried.**

- imploding arrays.
- merging arrays.
- combining arrays.

But nothing worked.

Comment: Please show the code your tried.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then maybe those examples can help you.

Example #1:

```
$users = array(83);
$dataUsers = [];

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $queryselectuser = mysqli_query($connect,"SOME QUERY");
    $itemCollection = [];
    while($recFile=mysqli_fetch_array($queryselectuser)) 
    {
       $item = [];
       $item['request_id'] = $recFile['request_id'];
       $item['fixer_id'] = $recFile['fixer_id'];
       $itemCollection[] = item;
    }
    $dataUsers[] = $itemCollection;
}
```

Example #2 (by using [`mysqli_fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)):

```
$users = array(83);
$dataUsers = [];
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $queryselectuser = mysqli_query($connect,"SOME QUERY");
    $dataUsers[] = mysqli_fetch_all($queryselectuser, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both examples work perfectly fine if I have one value in ```$users = array(83);``` . But if I have more then one value ```$users = array(83,84);``` then the data repeat it self.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes about the code:

- You get that result of only just the arrays, as you are directly printing `print_r($l);` in the loop
- If you want a collection of arrays, you can create an array `$items` for example, and on each iteration create a new array adding the values for request_id and fixer_id to it. Then use the userid as the key to be able to correlate the data afterwards if necessary
- In the example code you are not using the value of `$user` from the foreach loop. It may be obvious, but the get the data related to that user, you have to use that value in your query

For example using your example code:

```
$users = array(83, 84);
$items = [];

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $queryselectuser =  mysqli_query($connect,"SOME QUERY");
    while($rec_file = mysqli_fetch_array($queryselectuser))
    {           
        $l['request_id']= $rec_file['request_id'];
        $l['fixer_id']= $rec_file['fixer_id'];
        $items[$user] = $l;
    }
}
print_r($items);
```

Example output

```
Array
(
    [83] => Array
        (
            [request_id] => request_id_1
            [fixer_id] => fixer_id_1
        )

    [84] => Array
        (
            [request_id] => request_id_2
            [fixer_id] => fixer_id_2
        )

)
```

Comment: ```
)
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[request_id] => 1505
[fixer_id] => 84
)

[1] => Array
(
[request_id] => 1489
[fixer_id] => 84
)

[2] => Array
(
[request_id] => 1473
[fixer_id] => 84
)

[3] => Array
(
[request_id] => 1506
[fixer_id] => 83
)

[4] => Array
(
[request_id] => 1491
[fixer_id] => 83
)

[5] => Array
(
[request_id] => 1475
[fixer_id] => 83
)

)```
this is the result I am getting 2nd time if i use 2 values in ```$users```. I want separate array for each user with its records. I get first array okay, but 2nd array have the data of first user as well.

Comment: @ShoaibAsghar What do you mean by that?

Comment: Basically I want separate array for each user. an array of user 83 with its records, and then an array of user 84 with its records. the first array is fine, it provides the data of user 83 only. But second array provide data of both user 83 and 84. And if i use 3 value in ```$user[]={83,84,85}```. I get 3rd array with all three user's data.

Comment: @ShoaibAsghar What does the query look like? Did you use the example code, or the concept of it to use the key of each user is as the array key?

Comment: yes I have used the example concept...but that only provide me one array with one record of each user.

Comment: @ShoaibAsghar Then you can check if the id for that used already exists in resulting array. If it does not, you add that first array for that user id to an empty array. If the userid already exists (so there already is a key in the resulting array for that user) you add the array to the already existing array of arrays.